# any way to run gparted on cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, dd

I am creating bunch of SD-Card images for Android and find myself using dd and GParted a lot
Right now I reboot my laptop in PartedMagic from a USB drive

I have Cygwin on my Windows computer, which has dd

how can I get GParted too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gparted might be easy to compile on Cygwin, but it might not support Windows device identifiers, unless cygwin handles those automatically. It should, in that case, be a quick recompile - I do not believe a binary package for gparted is offered at this time.